# ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-

Tags: python, string

```
import glob

template = []
michi = []
z = 0
list_of_files = glob.glob('city011*') #list of txt files with city011
list_of_files2 =glob.glob('city012*') #list of txt files with city 012
for x in sorted(list_of_files):
i = 1
f = open(x, 'r')

while i < 65:
    template.append(f.readline())
    i += 1
else:
    f.close()


new_template = []
new_michi = []
character1 = template[0:2] #seperating the 1st and 2nd row 
character2 = michi[0:2]
I = int(template[2][0])# change str to float
J = int(michi[2][0])
l = template[3:63] #put all the numbers after row 4 to 63 to I
m = michi[3:63]
l = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in l]

m = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in m]

new_template = [[float(v) for v in row] for row in l]
 new_michi = [[float(v) for v in row]for row in m ]
```

The program above is the program made with Python 3 I am having an issue with. (Sorry with my english)

I would like to convert the list l and the list m in to string to float so I can do some mathmatics with the numbers that are included in the file I have imported. But no matter what I do I keep getting the error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-9dfc1a3477bd> in <module>
     19 m = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in m]
     20 
---> 21 t = [[float(v) for v in row] for row in l]
     22 m = [[float(v) for v in row]for row in m ]
     23 

<ipython-input-66-9dfc1a3477bd> in <listcomp>(.0)
     19 m = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in m]
     20 
---> 21 t = [[float(v) for v in row] for row in l]
     22 m = [[float(v) for v in row]for row in m ]
     23 

<ipython-input-66-9dfc1a3477bd> in <listcomp>(.0)
     19 m = [i.split('\n')[0] for i in m]
     20 
---> 21 t = [[float(v) for v in row] for row in l]
     22 m = [[float(v) for v in row]for row in m ]
     23 

ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

I need the '-' since I have negative numbers in this list. What is the issue here? I am still new to programming and a little help will be very helpful. these are the two file I am using

```
city011_001
AZABU
61
-0.564886 -0.362052 -0.331799 0.027146 0.118848 0.102376 -0.038906 -0.097793 -0.104022 0.043500 0.191281 -0.064826 -0.069747 -0.062851 0.066074 
-0.066361 -0.534747 -0.542394 -0.393602 -0.023413 0.136101 0.092935 -0.057077 0.009687 0.238097 -0.014652 -0.200186 -0.034928 -0.057951 -0.003195 
0.842157 -0.778868 -0.105691 -0.312336 0.087421 0.204189 -0.041299 -0.049061 -0.009931 0.115195 0.001007 -0.182716 0.119833 -0.025959 -0.020513 
1.278850 -1.399424 0.067990 -0.769867 0.052095 0.294201 -0.167835 0.147297 -0.156301 0.370518 -0.024816 -0.283953 0.097187 -0.181163 0.049259 
1.421715 -1.230193 -0.225744 -0.724383 0.103701 0.194390 -0.075956 0.034107 -0.035347 0.310075 -0.032731 -0.198102 -0.003825 -0.093536 0.019162 
1.289699 -1.321113 -0.102069 -0.853993 0.164666 0.209930 -0.097758 0.066441 -0.048566 0.349875 -0.062024 -0.219468 -0.022268 -0.097542 0.036108 
1.249455 -1.238858 0.009236 -0.840980 0.070885 0.190261 -0.101935 0.085144 -0.027585 0.331549 0.018237 -0.272279 -0.037341 -0.092911 -0.007077 
1.224821 -1.370419 0.127091 -0.762480 -0.010266 0.129633 -0.063520 0.015222 0.083793 0.277739 0.016615 -0.238389 -0.023894 -0.087033 -0.037941 
1.191334 -1.330720 0.177719 -0.664881 -0.040467 0.085474 -0.158575 -0.021745 0.229091 0.284875 -0.038422 -0.259565 0.030907 -0.065734 -0.033000 
1.216255 -1.288188 0.311354 -0.643686 0.044548 -0.044176 -0.238597 0.030437 0.133794 0.386163 -0.120989 -0.185939 0.110722 -0.094614 0.019909 
1.395151 -1.175099 0.419361 -0.507019 -0.011559 -0.135914 -0.300410 -0.055638 0.146501 0.400755 -0.160229 -0.089954 0.183122 -0.054810 -0.012017 
1.546437 -0.996897 0.333271 -0.304140 0.006562 -0.094147 -0.467173 -0.096743 0.097582 0.250509 -0.210891 0.051167 0.213547 -0.047487 0.122197 
1.414196 -0.672349 0.291445 -0.001192 0.221123 -0.070336 -0.396982 -0.152525 -0.042408 0.119944 -0.305183 -0.022731 0.157354 -0.089306 0.103051 
1.136524 -0.253834 0.268047 0.128915 0.174304 0.069094 -0.356221 -0.239891 0.037945 0.118614 -0.255114 -0.141221 0.095190 -0.046697 0.099950 
0.848878 -0.114963 0.087540 0.218149 0.205504 0.141213 -0.139472 -0.301806 0.074611 0.115555 -0.087639 -0.070352 -0.039854 -0.032816 0.087940 
0.608974 -0.419602 0.341482 0.279055 0.196700 0.194899 -0.233774 -0.127218 0.034112 0.086057 -0.004712 -0.136258 -0.017669 -0.031447 0.107335 
0.398919 -0.335132 0.084528 0.198119 0.230282 0.072961 -0.164834 0.070435 0.092392 0.016014 0.053750 -0.099828 -0.017675 0.149192 -0.070392 
0.359414 -0.430793 0.280225 0.131803 -0.028128 -0.028833 -0.065976 0.032417 -0.045087 -0.073830 0.058469 0.018988 -0.039880 -0.036854 0.072766 
0.711401 -0.609370 0.361248 -0.082942 0.096589 0.006496 -0.202951 0.040601 0.027924 0.047126 -0.060551 -0.008940 0.024021 -0.020911 0.080418 
1.520243 -0.872217 0.500197 -0.278433 0.046794 -0.000782 -0.462320 -0.081575 -0.002629 0.146519 -0.159297 -0.033698 0.183912 -0.019016 0.052579 
1.448077 -1.038008 0.524359 -0.398767 0.019172 -0.154791 -0.499288 -0.169826 0.080789 0.218585 -0.123081 0.027532 0.247998 0.055369 0.012356 
1.322387 -1.076368 0.427720 -0.529146 -0.001493 -0.164637 -0.349017 -0.126953 0.253717 0.283684 -0.115265 -0.034641 0.203598 -0.028300 -0.046986 
1.192419 -1.102404 0.467643 -0.627305 -0.012975 -0.226300 -0.223377 -0.117958 0.328307 0.331402 -0.053808 -0.069129 0.067321 -0.035456 -0.079906 
1.263399 -1.248433 0.389684 -0.633303 -0.058401 -0.169563 -0.143387 -0.000891 0.225259 0.312845 -0.009943 -0.174413 0.030837 -0.006666 -0.147230 
1.257705 -1.375028 0.356487 -0.644425 -0.061994 -0.119322 -0.087785 0.013549 0.180329 0.303469 -0.030254 -0.161451 -0.006156 -0.007527 -0.145331 
1.189983 -1.414042 0.326959 -0.672608 -0.034861 -0.115374 -0.055163 -0.004175 0.193968 0.257518 0.009719 -0.166211 -0.019698 -0.031926 -0.124341 
1.184256 -1.402893 0.330787 -0.663400 -0.053992 -0.107616 -0.063749 -0.006215 0.195485 0.262282 -0.012895 -0.120505 -0.035840 -0.037871 -0.122054 
1.229957 -1.384590 0.370079 -0.693345 -0.091604 -0.109960 -0.048492 0.008776 0.175603 0.237529 0.021885 -0.074114 -0.074001 -0.052375 -0.093756 
1.229254 -1.332572 0.363084 -0.669279 -0.118021 -0.144251 -0.035450 -0.005901 0.161276 0.228155 0.065153 -0.060899 -0.057344 -0.060287 -0.104245 
1.231809 -1.275436 0.376810 -0.679418 -0.136494 -0.147156 -0.064548 -0.073682 0.171361 0.225998 0.106094 -0.016500 -0.031727 -0.041949 -0.154154 
1.223847 -1.148237 0.421010 -0.672443 -0.033970 -0.179690 -0.163458 -0.198835 0.088242 0.385321 0.091737 -0.028943 0.084270 -0.053630 -0.076178 
1.484004 -1.049774 0.445218 -0.566597 0.051024 -0.008434 -0.360900 -0.252436 -0.086856 0.266731 0.053113 -0.013419 0.189292 -0.047879 0.017011 
1.657123 -0.970894 0.544177 -0.540018 0.022996 0.152599 -0.554293 -0.136169 -0.254624 0.234994 0.030891 -0.061473 0.242975 -0.084672 0.070589 
1.607733 -0.501813 0.501149 -0.389062 0.152247 0.282289 -0.386162 -0.187716 -0.180411 0.231679 0.022476 -0.175087 0.109753 -0.126024 0.054657 
1.473333 -0.526581 0.469268 -0.305862 0.149021 0.324656 -0.490135 -0.257430 -0.209352 0.114876 0.027539 -0.237509 0.120990 -0.130941 0.046021 
1.653905 -0.493418 0.524019 -0.349304 0.156857 0.227242 -0.451912 -0.209022 -0.228119 0.143476 -0.007884 -0.240565 0.123461 -0.074670 0.028463 
1.536309 -0.518010 0.582219 -0.321808 0.163296 0.165591 -0.489834 -0.193279 -0.284768 0.155241 0.071616 -0.287633 0.098826 -0.004139 0.032808 
1.644538 -0.503939 0.613541 -0.388342 0.285326 0.069827 -0.395457 -0.123743 -0.404200 0.128826 -0.001998 -0.204022 0.036513 -0.030668 0.032190 
1.541992 -0.610647 0.592973 -0.529962 0.201122 0.095443 -0.536618 -0.128686 -0.369740 0.252843 0.021825 -0.146084 0.160770 -0.074382 0.109616 
1.499032 -0.751420 0.699365 -0.492554 0.209540 0.015254 -0.529524 -0.134525 -0.268661 0.190877 -0.091176 -0.143813 0.192274 -0.033891 0.091421 
1.480328 -0.762546 0.740153 -0.515755 0.216586 -0.004267 -0.579273 -0.133383 -0.132875 0.112759 -0.149488 -0.097211 0.175728 0.022434 0.077614 
1.531924 -0.909482 0.739426 -0.454037 0.141057 -0.073841 -0.523263 -0.006819 -0.189210 0.091149 -0.101432 -0.102132 0.240585 -0.004541 0.015137 
1.564920 -0.901799 0.797734 -0.443603 0.151326 0.018649 -0.638810 -0.038640 -0.179274 0.168794 -0.162830 -0.168921 0.257691 0.015693 0.026674 
1.586304 -0.970958 0.828708 -0.431585 0.158889 -0.007032 -0.599201 -0.020189 -0.194712 0.159612 -0.153830 -0.175926 0.260680 0.007664 0.011571 
1.521087 -0.919795 0.809920 -0.401365 0.173541 0.012069 -0.608099 -0.081178 -0.165727 0.154590 -0.137378 -0.202519 0.223397 0.055397 0.003724 
1.535179 -0.895967 0.814063 -0.417202 0.182985 0.003347 -0.578630 -0.093795 -0.173034 0.159203 -0.146497 -0.182633 0.189117 0.072476 0.003394 
1.498250 -0.846374 0.811723 -0.379171 0.152834 0.006708 -0.556147 -0.099243 -0.170304 0.154079 -0.127289 -0.175990 0.173268 0.070970 0.003155 
1.502411 -0.849618 0.804613 -0.359136 0.149692 0.031262 -0.572666 -0.097179 -0.170351 0.147785 -0.113596 -0.172508 0.152918 0.063855 0.035915 
1.460480 -0.815167 0.757607 -0.324051 0.157150 0.054370 -0.557047 -0.169776 -0.138498 0.109355 -0.102176 -0.179501 0.132161 0.053532 0.050886 
1.533028 -0.903879 0.755382 -0.322951 0.156190 0.083547 -0.561185 -0.146690 -0.181334 0.108471 -0.122671 -0.175944 0.143827 0.021591 0.041499 
1.456504 -0.845514 0.724111 -0.273281 0.145048 0.059580 -0.528181 -0.185858 -0.151950 0.056892 -0.084365 -0.198770 0.125084 0.061101 -0.000526 
1.543965 -0.874505 0.779355 -0.275183 0.104164 0.074192 -0.526707 -0.162817 -0.186872 0.083728 -0.095147 -0.210600 0.150540 0.042756 0.001423 
1.523564 -0.844999 0.742627 -0.239259 0.081074 0.087702 -0.566088 -0.137143 -0.221413 0.123895 -0.079427 -0.237290 0.181148 0.033403 0.008768 
1.587095 -0.827221 0.766653 -0.263064 0.125951 0.067477 -0.588531 -0.111997 -0.303022 0.191861 -0.053438 -0.328038 0.210766 0.038512 0.023727 
1.551759 -0.688132 0.729177 -0.215355 0.039286 0.134421 -0.659897 -0.086744 -0.383137 0.249414 -0.036489 -0.363021 0.275923 -0.000572 0.034495 
1.444207 -0.435418 0.558001 -0.262199 0.114666 0.004387 -0.550021 -0.182094 -0.341897 0.195588 -0.051574 -0.375306 0.310519 0.004472 -0.014615 
1.507256 -0.064485 0.327781 -0.135720 0.216757 -0.140557 -0.434305 -0.305921 -0.303029 0.224082 -0.129693 -0.307061 0.213670 -0.002648 0.097647 
1.364793 -0.172069 0.290361 -0.006836 0.131982 -0.137962 -0.377829 -0.389034 -0.242236 0.225514 -0.172309 -0.307533 0.213262 0.064188 -0.003167 
0.692797 0.303743 0.412749 0.265486 -0.086380 -0.262810 -0.257429 -0.376094 -0.058311 -0.046480 -0.217281 -0.148514 0.215578 0.047842 -0.085526 
0.060232 0.037353 0.198756 0.297242 -0.163386 -0.061392 -0.333160 -0.358182 -0.203078 0.032988 -0.135661 -0.097065 0.036866 0.059062 0.070385 
-0.062064 -0.034975 0.094703 0.200314 0.031509 -0.142080 -0.334731 -0.284484 -0.044597 0.080181 -0.024795 -0.192018 0.104188 0.080460 0.088599 

city012_001
AZABU
64
-0.372859 -0.053422 0.178873 0.020878 -0.011901 0.085195 0.048618 0.068408 0.051098 -0.111088 0.067688 0.003582 0.006982 -0.027367 0.009338 
-0.228138 -0.136869 0.090660 0.067024 -0.077351 0.020984 -0.038191 -0.018700 0.177389 -0.174209 0.086777 -0.029544 -0.005567 0.032562 -0.062948 
0.884028 -0.603774 -0.148344 -0.587633 -0.012423 0.122845 0.037400 -0.111686 -0.018122 0.172289 0.096140 -0.187309 0.118508 -0.098796 -0.133073 
1.275520 -0.955523 -0.022245 -0.846167 0.091317 0.186486 -0.011860 -0.025662 0.062609 0.149853 0.116330 -0.317885 0.067682 -0.077208 -0.130428 
1.291267 -1.220943 -0.141300 -0.874721 0.139037 0.213898 -0.039492 0.068483 -0.076594 0.202987 0.162898 -0.355346 0.083203 -0.086413 -0.209573 
1.383232 -1.287588 -0.086338 -0.752371 0.093842 0.160523 0.062123 0.003882 -0.019083 0.122171 0.085804 -0.261097 0.101358 -0.100200 -0.091973 
1.411300 -1.206803 -0.185483 -0.634345 0.022095 0.201973 0.031433 0.027869 0.001632 0.086576 0.066079 -0.186346 0.023880 -0.099758 -0.021303 
1.596340 -1.343821 -0.179292 -0.706322 0.140294 0.091159 0.001936 -0.041036 0.045837 0.272982 0.001442 -0.229557 0.054179 -0.159230 -0.059235 
1.585099 -1.202238 -0.270017 -0.580217 0.045610 0.194129 0.015529 -0.081766 0.085021 0.202294 -0.009679 -0.222298 -0.002413 -0.071210 0.030696 
1.413655 -1.433315 0.167065 -0.812779 0.205131 0.022428 0.011379 -0.030921 0.084497 0.262418 -0.025609 -0.273947 0.043603 -0.096971 0.023384 
1.475440 -1.384373 0.245320 -0.666987 0.146153 -0.035756 -0.092091 0.023914 0.129753 0.281896 -0.098012 -0.222889 0.061091 -0.059055 -0.020177 
1.601381 -1.320165 0.202794 -0.525108 0.105248 -0.107294 -0.139861 -0.041641 0.171503 0.272161 -0.101581 -0.156422 0.105411 -0.060359 -0.004982 
1.603927 -1.244191 0.324301 -0.440618 0.180920 -0.245625 -0.150734 -0.026832 0.225230 0.247087 -0.126118 -0.093854 0.073799 -0.052203 0.019472 
1.623168 -0.987901 0.201583 -0.151870 0.237640 -0.296557 -0.149158 -0.145589 0.124458 0.206503 -0.151697 -0.056045 0.125241 -0.001614 0.036178 
1.425890 -0.495417 0.230789 0.098062 0.277886 -0.059787 -0.151610 -0.341973 0.017334 0.042043 -0.212903 -0.218417 0.086622 0.062213 -0.108881 
1.371843 -0.309074 0.199963 0.357738 0.064150 0.061121 -0.143253 -0.416712 0.063037 0.058477 -0.231011 -0.141733 0.023829 -0.026941 -0.031777 
1.032173 -0.246805 0.266806 0.290693 0.112305 0.109681 -0.169859 -0.256157 0.142742 -0.009360 -0.124307 -0.074634 -0.005550 0.000234 -0.032602 
0.644173 -0.162174 0.335125 0.180320 0.068894 0.099085 -0.082846 -0.043562 0.233364 0.122714 -0.029593 -0.091344 0.081930 0.126741 -0.107118 
0.475680 -0.438884 0.336833 0.251591 0.163709 0.099389 0.007750 -0.079359 0.174052 -0.036011 -0.007330 0.020206 0.041191 -0.037883 -0.002315 
0.297638 -0.623094 0.357094 0.144922 0.228439 0.037256 0.052872 -0.028198 0.028406 -0.062580 0.011996 0.146440 -0.034385 -0.127017 0.029929 
0.502427 -0.414017 0.533893 -0.061375 0.301187 -0.096956 -0.145014 -0.048261 0.022957 -0.155207 -0.024412 0.070557 -0.105280 0.008466 -0.039705 
1.379930 -0.943299 0.560217 -0.294474 0.086442 -0.148055 -0.358371 -0.269808 0.094976 0.098065 -0.087468 -0.030837 0.194419 0.011108 0.032291 
1.570165 -1.181364 0.653763 -0.504885 0.148711 -0.253795 -0.435209 -0.142262 0.103606 0.264452 -0.098557 -0.000212 0.239312 0.007722 0.030784 
1.525964 -1.388145 0.659017 -0.645787 0.135164 -0.188874 -0.325123 -0.026261 0.159531 0.317275 -0.072695 -0.107785 0.184888 -0.066110 -0.015970 
1.381049 -1.319826 0.492705 -0.717932 0.057874 -0.172862 -0.279095 -0.038384 0.233665 0.339216 -0.022850 -0.151863 0.155518 -0.077328 -0.094628 
1.425996 -1.251957 0.383858 -0.838682 0.110957 -0.181732 -0.198838 -0.059405 0.287145 0.276441 0.049446 -0.177993 0.071175 -0.061579 -0.115723 
1.428416 -1.195615 0.266160 -0.722955 0.035564 -0.143157 -0.110837 -0.080499 0.195500 0.361493 0.075407 -0.259140 0.014838 0.005572 -0.159230 
1.458574 -1.282877 0.271358 -0.731694 0.032315 -0.110611 -0.051280 -0.162049 0.231303 0.343527 0.066069 -0.249980 0.032270 -0.055878 -0.131908 
1.531575 -1.296950 0.311613 -0.766049 0.018352 -0.069836 -0.045184 -0.166073 0.208082 0.358298 0.051760 -0.203559 -0.015080 -0.055861 -0.133606 
1.417519 -1.256065 0.286256 -0.774775 0.013137 -0.056813 -0.086246 -0.130495 0.194672 0.340354 0.078235 -0.207533 -0.004194 -0.062196 -0.120885 
1.434281 -1.297624 0.372492 -0.840934 0.052790 -0.097955 -0.078635 -0.136779 0.211586 0.315463 0.082552 -0.166336 -0.024267 -0.048813 -0.136435 
1.399245 -1.238102 0.344601 -0.851675 0.060085 -0.115461 -0.103969 -0.122833 0.180895 0.305379 0.128682 -0.180927 0.033517 -0.072575 -0.138425 
1.448618 -1.282132 0.433648 -0.864181 0.083000 -0.150764 -0.128810 -0.170828 0.165979 0.337472 0.137190 -0.143567 0.057152 -0.081642 -0.110501 
1.545175 -1.306247 0.490940 -0.827797 0.123819 -0.156907 -0.189637 -0.212177 0.111066 0.321232 0.171898 -0.136541 0.144353 -0.103898 -0.070494 
1.776981 -1.202537 0.645499 -0.634117 0.122653 0.018608 -0.342009 -0.184320 -0.086391 0.242480 0.196317 -0.152195 0.161732 -0.080679 -0.039271 
1.523365 -0.974015 0.494479 -0.513496 0.087264 0.148210 -0.414593 -0.300500 -0.148377 0.038211 0.177925 -0.123650 0.211357 -0.036063 -0.118746 
1.538316 -0.567678 0.333441 -0.208497 0.144145 0.364683 -0.311333 -0.303108 -0.108416 -0.041805 0.109022 -0.282333 0.137896 -0.080224 -0.144619 
1.303020 -0.604061 0.495724 -0.042714 0.161392 0.281834 -0.326890 -0.233156 -0.164416 -0.007214 0.108075 -0.347446 0.073313 -0.004875 -0.205735 
1.384232 -0.526711 0.444002 -0.121688 0.197260 0.243993 -0.284887 -0.205504 -0.251058 -0.013724 0.166059 -0.345881 0.059512 0.007622 -0.225175 
1.488252 -0.588668 0.447268 -0.133353 0.189956 0.302414 -0.363129 -0.223852 -0.095709 -0.136148 0.144229 -0.279481 0.047655 -0.029214 -0.128663 
1.572980 -0.636961 0.569879 -0.301312 0.240446 0.281051 -0.411399 -0.229323 -0.029193 -0.088957 0.054242 -0.298142 0.120278 -0.022120 -0.116173 
1.622326 -0.639471 0.792291 -0.486051 0.294540 0.079367 -0.479563 -0.216699 -0.034541 0.107585 0.041113 -0.283134 0.169260 0.026297 -0.039865 
1.592481 -1.052805 0.890878 -0.388047 0.164796 -0.054416 -0.506141 -0.221445 -0.026343 0.133025 0.027844 -0.270933 0.259494 0.059280 -0.019812 
1.426453 -1.044021 0.861422 -0.357878 0.138641 -0.110128 -0.530623 -0.232881 -0.020247 0.094986 -0.030580 -0.192245 0.242282 0.094567 -0.005305 
1.533280 -1.135979 0.952082 -0.394677 0.161117 -0.161994 -0.482031 -0.215646 -0.050925 0.087057 -0.047038 -0.160309 0.241887 0.067510 -0.010451 
1.450723 -1.078848 0.935225 -0.370949 0.141140 -0.192116 -0.471523 -0.167311 -0.071692 0.055135 -0.078156 -0.137876 0.279759 0.035103 -0.053073 
1.509373 -1.099955 0.954656 -0.324036 0.135797 -0.238995 -0.457475 -0.132803 -0.090084 0.051315 -0.078161 -0.175185 0.319661 0.037660 -0.096943 
1.544964 -1.068859 0.886487 -0.246018 0.088797 -0.196022 -0.498889 -0.120109 -0.072688 0.038647 -0.071253 -0.211391 0.342662 0.045064 -0.108623 
1.636025 -1.076286 0.858571 -0.223016 0.086038 -0.195405 -0.481534 -0.150562 -0.049879 0.005525 -0.061361 -0.213454 0.317452 0.074504 -0.137559 
1.642545 -1.089763 0.865779 -0.184827 0.052418 -0.166947 -0.490114 -0.162684 -0.047244 -0.010228 -0.043690 -0.227407 0.298783 0.099639 -0.150343 
1.650773 -1.112748 0.919140 -0.201343 0.072065 -0.176207 -0.486870 -0.156129 -0.046868 -0.005950 -0.039129 -0.231829 0.292627 0.097018 -0.150992 
1.683027 -1.146003 0.966813 -0.195260 0.068532 -0.193437 -0.471582 -0.170708 -0.054849 0.006682 -0.020097 -0.233192 0.258461 0.139023 -0.155229 
1.580458 -1.068560 0.915983 -0.230605 0.107800 -0.199067 -0.468921 -0.185084 -0.048329 -0.003720 -0.032942 -0.258702 0.282779 0.126033 -0.141331 
1.541583 -1.080131 0.861356 -0.175994 0.051629 -0.169437 -0.473180 -0.188787 -0.076985 -0.016776 -0.021361 -0.252798 0.272483 0.133605 -0.152409 
1.589601 -1.052766 0.899937 -0.234341 0.090647 -0.171325 -0.491780 -0.164091 -0.136350 0.012998 0.028574 -0.326579 0.303084 0.139509 -0.170544 
1.414850 -0.941555 0.890409 -0.295902 0.116767 -0.152876 -0.513126 -0.143709 -0.212063 0.078100 0.046080 -0.373597 0.328973 0.137131 -0.171903 
1.340803 -0.892854 0.858321 -0.318484 0.149712 -0.166240 -0.524291 -0.152761 -0.186073 0.050031 0.075840 -0.407667 0.348113 0.164870 -0.205977 
1.149881 -0.873521 0.771120 -0.241362 0.159563 -0.216821 -0.494730 -0.160638 -0.216296 0.049305 0.023508 -0.377691 0.376416 0.101728 -0.190680 
1.256950 -0.571828 0.519614 -0.190852 0.237577 -0.203819 -0.430964 -0.199173 -0.245837 0.055972 -0.057430 -0.438551 0.403498 0.040059 -0.208375 
0.865023 0.171517 0.553042 0.056240 0.132775 -0.191963 -0.506706 -0.268398 -0.142724 0.118467 -0.085837 -0.426598 0.372870 0.154674 -0.133430 
0.964663 -0.043653 0.418481 0.076709 0.048039 -0.205359 -0.447605 -0.370963 -0.033215 0.042654 -0.059769 -0.378864 0.359603 0.102522 -0.056304 
0.395935 0.043478 0.294291 0.099131 -0.109979 -0.030208 -0.397982 -0.540739 0.008036 0.013974 -0.068067 -0.215936 0.151172 0.144677 0.008214 
0.159745 0.001086 0.175794 0.204451 -0.074011 -0.153243 -0.450696 -0.364899 0.071883 -0.069296 -0.047514 -0.161087 0.160672 0.156311 0.017193 
-0.050244 -0.323932 0.172993 0.040207 -0.145165 -0.000911 -0.348450 -0.282731 0.161845 0.135684 0.039978 -0.243819 0.212579 0.068541 -0.012944
```

Comment: Without looking closely, the start of your text is `city011_001 AZABU`, are you sure its not attempting to convert that into a float? If not, iterate through the list and convert each item to a float individually and find what value its breaking on.

Comment: I specifically divided the ones with words and numerals on the character1 = template[0:2] so I believe that this row is not the problem. i would check again

Answer (score 0):

```
append_file = f.readline()
template.append(append_file)
```

Thy this one and let me know if it worked or not.

Comment: Thank you for the swift answer. I have changed the 
    template.append(f.readline())  but it still gives me the same error